# Why is every input field purple?

Tags: themes, window, colors

In every app, every place where you'd expect there to be white, like the background of search boxes or the margins of documents the background is purple instead. Now, I happen to think purple is a fine color, but I don't remember making a setting like this. It makes my machine look ridiculous.

Examples:

[image]

[image]

I can't find a place to change this color. What is this setting even called? Any ideas?

This was an upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04.
I am currently using the Ambiance theme, although changing the theme doesn't seem to matter.
I am using Unity2D right now because of problems with my nvidia driver with 12.04. The color issue was still there even when I was using regular Unity.

Comment: this article may help you http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/enable-rgba-transparency-in-ubuntu-910.html

Comment: Sorry, @Nick, I don't see how that helps. I don't want to make them transparent, I just want them to be normal white or not purple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it was purple to begin with, but I installed GNOME Color Chooser and was able to override the setting by changing global colors -> Entry Fields -> normal -> Background to #ffffff.